# Faye Gem dependencies issue With Eventmachine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler
cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
faye was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
em-http-request was resolved to 1.1.7, which depends on
em-socksify was resolved to 0.3.2, which depends on
eventmachine

I have been facing this issue in my project. I have tried every single solution available on the internet but nothing works. My ruby version is 2.6.8
gem 'faye', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'

Comment: Please add the exact dependency errors to your question.

Comment: An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile: faye was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on em-http-request was resolved to 1.1.7, which depends on em-socksify was resolved to 0.3.2, which depends on eventmachine....... Everytime I received the same error of this kind, i have read a few blogs which says this happens due to dependencies. Furthermore i have updated the gem according to the shown error but nothing works. raised the same error.

Comment: @dbugger /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against
symbol `ssl_undefined_function' can not be used when making a shared object;
recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:262: rubyeventmachine.so] Error

Answer (score 1):

I found this on the October 13th comment on [the ticket here](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/932), and it worked for me:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@3
```

(Note: A 2020 comment recommends the same command with SSL 1.1 instead of 3.)

Comment: While the solution appears to be valid, it did not work in my scenario. I installed the mentioned gem, but the issue persists even after installation. The resolution seems to depend on upgrading relevant gems. It is important to check the versions of installed gems using 'gem list' and ensure they are compatible with the application. Update gems with 'gem update GEM_NAME' or all gems with 'gem update --system'. If using Bundler, run 'bundle update' to update gems in the Gemfile. Additionally, check and update the Gemfile.lock if necessary, and ensure compatibility.